# Swift issue with assigning OS constants

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use 2 OS constants as used in google sign in sdk. Here is my code:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {

 let appKey = UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey
 let annoKey = UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey

 return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,sourceApplication: options[appKey],
            annotation: options[annoKey])
}
```

But when I use `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey` and `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey` I am getting an error saying

> Use of unresolved identifier `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly format your inline code and blockquote - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Good luck!

Comment: did you add "`#import <Google/SignIn.h>`" or "`#import GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h`" to your project's bridging header file?

Comment: no luck @MichaelDautermann!!

Comment: Where are you using these constants and how are you calling them? I'm not familiar with google sign in, but you declared the constants in a function and the constant only have the scope of the function. I don't see where you are using these constants.

Comment: These constants are available in iOS 9 and above. Is your deployment target iOS 9?

Comment: No. iOS 8 and above @VinodVishwanath. Is there any alternative to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see `options` is a dictionary that can hold `String` as key, and `AnyObject` as value.

`let appKey = UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey`: in this line your `appKey` has a type `AnyObject`, so it cannot be send to `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()`. Try to cast it to string:

```
let appKey = UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey as? String
```

or

```
let appKey = UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey as! String
```

Comment: No. it's not the solution. Read my question again. "Use of unresolved identifier UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey". UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey is unresolved.